# Почему селектор родственного элемента распространяется на элементы вне родителя?

Tags: css

Привет. Взял с codepen [систему звёздочного рейтинга](https://codepen.io/michaelord/pen/mDfaj), не изменяя при этом принцип работы. Принцип действия в том, что все `span` после `<input checked>` отмечаются специальным цветом. Реализовано это родственным селектором `~`, который почему-то распространяет цвет только на последние звёзды на странице даже вне своего родителя. Почему так получается? Ведь родственный селектор не должен выбирать элементы вне родительского элемента.

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

.ticket_star-rating {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.rating {
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.rating > input {
    display: none;
}
.rating > label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f005";
}
.rating > .half:before {
    content: "\f089";
    position: absolute;
}
.rating > label {
    color: #ddd;
    float: right;
}
.rating > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket_star-rating">
    <div class="rating">
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="10" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star5" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="9" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half">
        <label for="star4half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="8" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" checked="checked">
        <label for="star4" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="7" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half">
        <label for="star3half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="6" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star3" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="5" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half">
        <label for="star2half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="4" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star2" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="3" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half">
        <label for="star1half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="2" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="star1" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="1" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half">
        <label for="starhalf" class="half"></label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ticket_star-rating">
    <div class="rating">
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="10" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="star5" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="9" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half">
        <label for="star4half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="8" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" checked="checked">
        <label for="star4" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="7" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half">
        <label for="star3half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="6" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="star3" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="5" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half">
        <label for="star2half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="4" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="star2" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="3" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half">
        <label for="star1half" class="half"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="2" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="star1" class="full"></label>
        <input disabled="" type="radio" data-star-num="1" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half">
        <label for="starhalf" class="half"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: куда смотреть? Что именно не так?

Comment: @MedvedevDev запустите снипет. Согласно стилям, звёзды должны быть заполнены и в первом, и во втором блоках. Но заполнены они будут по какой-то причине только в последнем. Хоть сколько таких блоков не дублируй.

Comment: у тебя задан `name` один и тот же у всех `input`, ты их сделай видимыми, увидишь, что чекнут только последний. В общем задай разным группам звезд разные name и будет все ок.

Comment: Ну и for, id тоже индивидуальные нужны

Comment: @MedvedevDev спасибо!